# When condition inside if statement is fractional

Tags: c, if-statement, output, continue

```
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        if(i/5)
            continue;
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

My simple query is,if the condition inside "if" is evaluated to a fraction,is it treated as 0?As here the output is 1234,so when condition is 1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5 it is prinnting values of i,when 5/5=1 it is executing continue statement.

Comment: What are the *integer division* rules?

Comment: `i/5` is an integer divison (no floating-point operands), thus the result is truncated (fractional part is discarded).

Comment: If you only want to know something about a division operation, why do you ask some stuff about "condition inside if"? The division will be done in the same way in any other place as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i/5` will be treated as integer division (when `i` is `int` of course), no matter where it appears in (`if` or whatever). So `/` between two integers will actually give you the quotient.

`i / 5` will give `0` when `i ∈ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` and `1` when `i = 5`.

The `if` statement executes the conditional statement (in this case the `continue` statement ) when its conditional expression is `true`. An integer value is casted to boolean as follows: zero becomes `false`, any other value becomes `true`. Since the expression does not evaluate to a non-zero value until `i==5`, the conditional statement is not executed until then.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have

```
if ( expr )
```

and the `expr` isn't obviously something that's true/false, you can always think of it like this:

```
if( (expr) != 0)
```

So if the `expr` evaluates to something fractional, well, as long as the fraction is not equal to 0, the condition will evaluate as true.

However, in your example, since `i` is an integer, `i/5` will do integer division which will never give a fraction.  And if `i` is less than 5, `i/5` will be 0, which will end up making the conditional false.